# Import from CSV to File

Tags: powershell, csv, export

I'm trying to write a script to extract 2 variables 'code' and 'description' and write them into this template.

```xml
<CodeDescriptions>
  <CodeDescription>
    <Code>*code*</Code>
    <Description>*description*</Description>
  </CodeDescription>
</CodeDescriptions>
```

For every set of variables it finds it writes the template and inserts the variables.

my CSV file looks like this

```
code,description
0001,first
0002,second
0003,third
```

My code so far:

```bsh
$DB = Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\Variables.csv

Set-Content $PSScriptRoot\file.txt

    foreach ($Entry in $DB) {
        $First = $Entry.First
        $Second = $Entry.Second

        # Echo values to verify result (test purposes only)
        Write-Host $First
        Write-Host $Second

        # Write template to file
         $var= 
         "<CodeDescriptions>
             <CodeDescription>
                <Code>*code*</Code>
                <Description>*description*</Description>
             </CodeDescription>
          </CodeDescriptions>"

         Add-Content $PSScriptRoot\file.txt $var

        # replace inserts with correct variables
    }
```

As I said i'm still getting familiar with the code my goal is to extract 2 variables from 1 line at a time. Then write the template to a file with the correct variables and loop that until all variables are entered.

The finished product would look like this

```
<CodeDescriptions>
  <CodeDescription>
    <Code>0001</Code>
    <Description>first</Description>
  </CodeDescription>
</CodeDescriptions>
<CodeDescriptions>
  <CodeDescription>
    <Code>0002</Code>
    <Description>second</Description>
  </CodeDescription>
</CodeDescriptions>
<CodeDescriptions>
  <CodeDescription>
    <Code>0003</Code>
    <Description>third</Description>
  </CodeDescription>
</CodeDescriptions>
```

Comment: So you have the variables extracted from the csv then you want to print they as xml? Please edit your answer to make it more clear

Comment: Why do you assign the same value (`$Entry`) to 2 variables (`$First` and `$Second`), and why are you using a subexpression (`$()`) for that? What is the structure of your CSV? Where do you read the XML (I suppose that's your template)?

Comment: I have updated to add more to the description. Will try to update the code correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems.

First of all, Import-Csv defines the names of the properties based on the headers in the first row, so your foreach loop which starts like this:

```
foreach ($Entry in $DB) {
    $First = $Entry.First
    $Second = $Entry.Second
```

Should start like this:

```
foreach ($Entry in $DB) {
    $Code = $Entry.Code
    $Description = $Entry.Description
```

Then you need to replace `*code*` with `$Code` and `*description*` with `$Description` in your `$var` (or skip the intermediary variable and just write:

```
Add-Content $PSScriptRoot\file.txt @"
<CodeDescriptions>
    <CodeDescription>
        <Code>$Code</Code>
        <Description>$Description</Description>
    </CodeDescription>
</CodeDescriptions>
"@
```